# Displaying latest satellite images and adding shapefiles on globes other than Google Earth?

Tags: 3d, google-earth, arcglobe

Are there alternatives to Google Earth that will display the latest satellite images and can add pinpoints and are relatively intuitive?

It would be nice if I could possibly add shapefiles  on top of the satellite images.

I have tried ArcGlobe which is interesting but many layers like boundaries and lakes need to be added manually, and navigation is a little clumsy.

Comment: Nasa World Wind is java based and opensource http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Answer (score 5):

If your main reason for looking for another software is adding *shapefiles*, then you can actually stick with Google and use **Google Earth Pro**.

[Google Earth Pro](http://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html) is able to load shapefiles, and as of [January 2015](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176160?hl=en) you can get it for free. All you need to do is get a key, and then you can download the program. You can look into its [functionality](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/189188?hl=en) and decide whether it suits your needs.

I have not tried it personally, but the *bulk geocoding* functionality seems really useful!

**EDIT**:
based on the comment below, I would also like to add that [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) could be an option. Although I am not aware of any products that do exactly what you would like to do, there are at least a few attempts out there to use WebGL with geographic data and globes, such as [these ones (scroll down for some neat examles)](https://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe).
 [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/mapbox-gl-js/) is also getting started in that area, so I am sure we can except some really cool things very soon.

Of course, this would require that you do all your work in a browser, instead of a desktop application, which may or may not be suitabe.

Comment: I like to avoid Google products when possible as I don't like their data handling policy and especially don't like the extra services and background tasks they add to my computer when I install any of their software.

Comment: That is understandable. I posted this because I thought you would be looking specifically for a way to display shapefiles. Other users might also look this question up because they are not aware that GEPro can do this. The other thing I could thing of is *WebGL*. You could look into that, but, of course, it would require that you use a browser instead of a desktop app.

Answer (score 3):

[ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer) may be an option for you.

Otherwise the [alternativeto.net website](http://alternativeto.net/software/google-earth/) provides a list of other alternatives.

Comment: i have looked at that list but it's mostly apps and websites that are not even comparable to GEP

Answer (score 1):

TerraExplorer Viewer is a free tool that can easily ingest KML\KMZ's in a 3D environment.  Adding pinpoints is a built-in functionality and navigation is a breeze.  Below is the download link to TerraExplorer Viewer.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

http://skylinesoft.com/SkylineGlobe/corporate/home/index.aspx? (download TerraExplorer)

Answer (score -3):

You can try KML search tool which complements Google Earth and handles shapefiles, CSV, and KMZ.

Here is a [link](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/KML-Search-Tool.shtml)

Comment: Can you add a link to the KML search tool, or more information? As it stands this information above is not very useful